# Missing RAM on 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 64-bit, ram

BIOS shows 6 GB of RAM installed, but only 3.1 GiB RAM is shown in the about page of settings.

Ubuntu is 18.04.5, 64 bit version.

Following is output from `free`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3201636     1896440      385668       73784      919528     1004104
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148
```

Output from `uname -a`:

```
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The output from `grep --color=always -i PAE /proc/cpuinfo` shows that PAE is supported.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you run memtest? That's a huge amount of RAM to be used for an on-board video card (changeable in the BIOS) so I doubt that's it. I'd run memtest to see what it says.

Comment: How is the RAM *physically* installed?  6GB is uncommon because RAM is ideally installed in identical pairs and neither 3GB or 6GB are common sizes for modules.  Some motherboards also require that RAM be installed in specific slots depending on the number of slots used.  I suggest reviewing your motherboard documentation and the physical orientation of your RAM sticks

Comment: @Nmath The RAM is 4+2. I've tried switching the RAM between slots, but that didn't work. It still showed 3.1 GiB. This is a laptop that I'm using. My BIOS shows 6 GB installed whichever way I install the RAM cards. I tried a 4+4, but that too showed only 3.1 GiB in Ubuntu. I used Windows before, and it used to show above 5 GB of RAM.

Comment: @KGIII I ran memtest and the check passed. I found no setting related to video card memory usage in my BIOS. I had some moderately heavy programs running when I ran `free`. That might be the reason the usage is high in above sample.